# Matching simple Array values using php

Tags: php, arrays, user-agent

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 

$device_array = array("iPhone" , "iPad", "Android");
```

What I'd like to do is write a simple if statement that looked at to see if any of `$device_array` values exist in the `$useragent` string but not sure how to construct it.

Is there a way of doing this ideally without iterating over the array values?

Comment: I think I've seen this question at least 3 times today. Have you Googled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
if( in_array( $useragent, $device_array)) {
    echo $useragent . ' is in the array!';
}
```

**Edit:** For a wildcard match, you can use a regex:

```
$device_array = array("iPhone" , "iPad", "Android");
$regex = '#' . implode( '|', $device_array) . '#i'; // Note: Escaping the elements in the array with preg_quote() has been omitted
if( preg_match( $regex, $useragent)) { 
    echo $useragent . ' was matched in the array!';
}
```

Comment: Although he didn't exactly say this, I think he's trying to see if any of those strings are contained in the `$useragent` which would require a wildcard search (regex or `strstr`...).  I don't believe `in_array` would handle this, would it?

Comment: Yes @AdamPlocher that's what I was after.  I want to check to see if the $useragent string matched any of the array values ie "iPhone", "iPad" etc etc.

Comment: @user1563944 I've edited my answer to show a matching method using a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks @nickb that's perfect for what I was trying to do!

Comment: It's the regex delimiter. More on delimeters in PCRE is at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php